# Avoid line breaks in bootstrap button group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a bootstrap button group which includes a text between the buttons:

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div>2016</div>
                <div class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How to avoid the line breaks, such that the buttons and the text are aligned in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to display them in-line like:

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">2016</div>
                <div class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

---

**Edit**: Alternatively, as Turnip proposed in his answer, you can change the elements from `div`s to to another kind of element that is naturally displayed in-line. Either way, you will reach the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`div`s are block elements. Change your buttons to `<a>`s and the text div to a `<span>` or any other inline/inline-block element.

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </a>
                <span>2016</span>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, here it works fine. But when I do a copy&past exact of your solution code, in my app the number "2016" is aligned right to the second button and not between the buttons. Any idea, what could make the difference?

Comment: Use your browsers dev tools to inspect the element that contains "2016" and look at the CSS applied. I would guess that there is `text-align: right` somewhere in your CSS. Or perhaps you have the class `text-right` on an ancestor?